# customizing UICollectionView.contentOffset prior to appearance

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView where I want to set the collectionView.contentOffset.x value to the screen's midpoint. I want the collectionView's content to start at the screen's midpoint but to be scrollable to the left of that. Using collectionView.setContentOffset, I can do it after the view appears. However, I want it to appear on the screen when the view loads, already at that position.

I've tried using

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {     
    return CGPoint(x: collectionView.frame.width/2, y: 0)
}
```

but it has no effect. My delegate and dataSource are set.

I've tried using collectionView.setContentOffset in viewDidLoad, then in viewDidLayoutSubviews, animated set to false. This didn't work.

Do I need a custom layout, or can I do without?

Comment: Try in `viewWillAppear`

Comment: Doesn't work there either.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, so found the answer on my own. In short, updating the UI on the main thread was the answer. Calling

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
     self?.scrubberCollectionView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: (self?.collectionViewStartingPoint)!, y: 0), animated: false)
}
```

from ViewDidLoad() worked like a charm. I saw it right after I started this morning. I really didn't think this question required me to post my code, but someone else might have seen it right away.

So, three takeaways: post code on StackOverflow, update the UI on the main thread, and take a break occasionally.